# Magento 2 - Change category description, position and name programmatically

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, name

How can I change name desciption, position and image attributes for a category using code. I tried this code for changing the name, but without success:

```
// $_this->cm is \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
$c=$this->cm->loadByAttribute("pim_category_id", $pimCategoryId);

        $c->setData("name", "testingNaminho");
        $c->setName("via setName setted");
        $c->setData("description", $description);
        $c->setData("position", $position);
        //$c->setData("image", $name);

        $c->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

And Now:

```
$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

//Add your save operation here
```

Comment: I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Hi Sohel Rana, can you pls help me how to change category description based on attributes selection https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/329971/57334

Answer (score 0):

Check the store id of the saved category attribute. Likely the value saved in db but the store id is not General